# Running OS X Apps On Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

Is there any way that still works to run OS X apps on Ubuntu 14.04? If Darling still works, please tell me how to install it.

Thanks. :)

Comment: Look here https://github.com/darlinghq/darling

Comment: How can I install it @Terrance?

Answer (score 3):

OK, it took me a while to figure out the whole install, but I don't know how to successfully use `Darling` yet.

---

Below is the step-by-step procedure I followed to get `Darling` installed, and some of the steps were followed from the `README.md` from the git repository.

Open a terminal and run the following commands:

*First install the tools to build and make darling.*

```
sudo apt-get install git cmake clang bison flex xz-utils libfuse-dev libxml2-dev libicu-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev libudev-dev linux-headers-generic
```

*Run git to download the darling source files.*

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/darlinghq/darling.git
```

*One-by-one copy and paste the following to build, make and install the darling application.*

```
cd darling
mkdir -p build/x86-64
cd build/x86-64
cmake ../.. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../../Toolchain-x86_64.cmake
make
sudo make install
```

*One-by-one copy and paste the following to build, make and install the Kernel module.*

```
cd ../../src/lkm
make
sudo make install
```

*For some reason the Kernel module didn't install correctly, so the next 3 lines copy and install it for you.*

```
sudo cp darling-mach.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/
sudo bash -c 'echo "darling-mach" >> /etc/modules'
sudo depmod
```

*I recommend a reboot for the Kernel modules to load correctly.*

```
sudo reboot
```

*After the reboot, you can check to see if it loaded correctly.*

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ darling shell
Darling [~]$ uname -a 
Darwin terrance-ubuntu 12.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.0.0 x86_64
Darling [~]$ exit
exit
```

Hope this helps!